# What is the bindings parameter for the block in predicateWithBlock: used for?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nspredicate

The declaration for `+[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]` looks like this:

```
+ (NSPredicate *)predicateWithBlock:(BOOL (^)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings))block
```

Apple's documentation for the second parameter to the block, `bindings`, says that it is:

> The substitution variables dictionary. The dictionary must contain key-value pairs for all variables in the receiver.

I can't figure out why this parameter is needed -- nor have I seen it being used anywhere. Why is it there?

Also, do I need to look inside `bindings` when using a block based predicate with `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`?

Comment: An answer here with an example of where and how to *use* the `bindings` parameter would be very useful!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the class documentation:

> You can also create predicates that include variables, so that the
>   predicate can be pre-defined before substituting concrete values at
>   runtime. In Mac OS X v10.4, for predicates that use variables,
>   evaluation is a two step process (see
>   predicateWithSubstitutionVariables: and evaluateWithObject:). In Mac
>   OS X v10.5 and later, you can use
>   evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:, which combines these steps.

Then check out the [predicate syntax docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB).

---

If you were to subsequently invoke `evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:`, said dictionary would be passed to your block.   This enables rather generic predicate creation where the resulting predicate can be passed around and a consistent substitution language can be used for evaluation.

Comment: When you define a predicate with string format, I can see the usefulness of substitution variables. But I still don't understand how substitution variables can be used when you create a predicate using `predicateWithBlock:`. (An example would be great)

Comment: Ah, I can now see what you mean. Also, is the bindings parameter used at all when the predicate is created to be passed to `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`? My guess is not.

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert link is no longer valid, do you have any more references?

Comment: Sorry, kinda stupid this internet ;)
https://web.archive.org/web/20160330070114/http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=149

Comment: And sure, archive.org has it all! :D